# Spring Boot multiple controllers with same mapping

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot

My problem is very similar with this one: [Spring MVC Multiple Controllers with same @RequestMapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607396/spring-mvc-multiple-controllers-with-same-requestmapping)

I'm building simple Human Resources web application with Spring Boot. I have a list of jobs and individual url for each job:

> localhost:8080/jobs/1

This page contains job posting details and a form which unauthenticated users -applicants, in this case- can use to apply this job. Authenticated users -HR Manager-, can see only posting details, not the form. I have trouble with validating form inputs.

What I tried first:

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    private final AppService appService;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationController(AppService appService) {
        this.appService = appService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jobs/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleApplyForm(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute("form") ApplyForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "job_detail"; //HTML page which contains job details and the application form
        }
        appService.apply(form, id);
        return "redirect:/jobs";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/applications/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getApplicationPage(@PathVariable Long id) {
        if (null == appService.getAppById(id)) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(String.format("Application=%s not found", id));
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("application_detail", "app", appService.getAppById(id));
        }
    }
}
```

As you guess this didn't work because I couldn't get the models. So I put `handleApplyForm()` to `JobController` and changed a little bit:

```
@Controller
public class JobController {

    private final JobService jobService;
    private final AppService appService;

    @Autowired
    public JobController(JobService jobService, AppService appService) {
        this.jobService = jobService;
        this.appService = appService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jobs/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView handleApplyForm(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute("form") ApplyForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return getJobPage(id);
        }

        appService.apply(form, id);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/jobs");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jobs/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getJobPage(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if (null == jobService.getJobById(id)) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException(String.format("Job=%s not found", id));
        } else {
            model.put("job", jobService.getJobById(id));
            model.put("form", new ApplyForm());
        }

        return new ModelAndView("job_detail", model);
    }
}
```

With this way, validations works but I still can't get the same effect [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) as it refreshes the page so that all valid inputs disappear and error messages don't appear.

By the way, `job_detail.html` is like this:

```
<h1>Job Details</h1>
<p th:inline="text"><strong>Title:</strong> [[${job.title}]]</p>
<p th:inline="text"><strong>Description:</strong> [[${job.description}]]</p>
<p th:inline="text"><strong>Number of people to hire:</strong> [[${job.numPeopleToHire}]]</p>
<p th:inline="text"><strong>Last application date:</strong> [[${job.lastDate}]]</p>

<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <form th:action="@{/jobs/} + ${job.id}" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete this posting" name="delete" />
    </form>
 </div>

<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
    <h1>Application Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/jobs/} + ${job.id}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" th:value="${form.firstName}" />
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('form.firstName')}" th:errors="${form.firstName}"></td>
        </div>

        <!-- and other input fields -->

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="apply" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check thymeleaf documentation [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html)

> Values for th:field attributes must be selection expressions (*{...}),

Also `ApplyForm` is exposed then you can catch it in the form.

Then your form should looks like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/jobs/} + ${job.id}" th:object="${applyForm}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" th:value="*{firstName}" />
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}"></td>
        </div>

        <!-- and other input fields -->

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="apply" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: It didn't change anything man. I don't think that problem is showing error messages. If problem was this, valid inputs wouldn't disappear. Problem is refreshing of page as I call `getJobPage()` method in `handleApplyForm()`. But this is the only way validation works, I don't know how to control it otherwise.